# Call to a possibly undefined method as im trying to instantiate the Movie Clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

Okay, so i have a bunch of simple shapes in movie clips...

THen, i have "levels" that are each in their own movie clip...

Sometimes in the levels i have to instantiate these random movie clips on the fly and create multiple instances, so ill just do something like

```
//this up top
var hexagonOne:hexagonOne;


//then this when i need a new one, i need to do it like this so i can make multiple instances...
hexagonOne = new hexagonOne();
```

This works great..but...

in another movie clip now on my "level 2" movie clip

I literally take the same exact code, that worked in level one...But now it will not work in this other movie clip....

I get this error whenever i try `hexagonOne = new hexagonOne();` or ANY other shape movie clip i try to instantiate.

```
Symbol 'lvl1-2', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 99  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method hexagonOne.
```

I don't understand because it worked fine inside the other movie clip, which is just like this one...It makes no sense.

EDIT:
figured it out, dumb typo on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a symbol in your library with AS Linkage named "hexagonOne", this makes sense:

```
var hexagonOne:hexagonOne;
hexagonOne = new hexagonOne();
```

From the timeline, you define a local variable `hexagonOne` and instantiate that instance with a type `hexagonOne`.

If you have not defined the variable `var hexagonOne` in a different scope, it's unknown.

For starters, it'd probably help to follow a naming convention for your symbol to be defined as `HexagonOne` then camel case your variable as you have.

```
var hexagonOne:HexagonOne;
hexagonOne = new HexagonOne();
```

If each level MovieClip needs to add a `hexagonOne` object, each should define `var hexagonOne:hexagonOne` and instantiate it with the new keyword.

If that doesn't help, perhaps you should cite more of what your trying to accomplish with specifics of your libary / class / code implementation.

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, lets just say i have lvlone_mc and lvltwo_mc then inside both of them i have var hexagonOne:HexagonOne;
hexagonOne = new HexagonOne(); in lvlone_mc i get no errors. in lvltwo_mc i see an error. It's seriously making no sense to me. ive got the same exact code in both.

Comment: Are they both just MovieClips?  In the same library?  What is HexagonOne - a symbol in the library?  Is "var hexagonOne..." the line of code at Line 99?  Is there any additional code in either level MovieClip?

Comment: oh man. I'm really out of it, thanks for pointing out the whole camel case thing. I thought for sure i was constructing it as `new HexagonOne();` but nope, of couse, i overlooked it and it was with a lower case h. It's due tomorrow so i wasn't thinking rationally. lol thanks!